# In Java, will empty collections of the same type, but different type parameters always be equal?

Tags: java, generics, equals

Consider the following snippet:

```
    List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
    assertThat(list1.equals(list2), is(true));
```

The assertion succeeds.

Indeed, as far as I understand, there is no way in Java, for the `equals` method to differentiate between the two, due to run-time type-erasure (i.e. the fact the type arguments `String` and `Integer` are only accessible at compile-time, but not at run-time).
And since there are no elements, which could be compared, `equals` has to return true. And by this line of thought, this must be true, for all collections.

So the question is the following: is my thought process correct, or am I missing something?

**EDIT**

@qqilihq gave an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47727878/3398271), which prompts the next question:
Is this possible to achieve without **passing** the type explicitly (I'm fine if the type is **stored** explicitly somehow, just the user does should not have to pass it.)

I attempted the following, but it did not work (I guess due to type erasure):

```
    public TypedList(List<T> delegate) {
        this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
        this.type = (Class<T>) delegate.getClass();
    }
```

But maybe you can do something similar to this? `this.type = T`. (This does not compile, but maybe something similar would be possible.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you state, the type information is lost at runtime in your given example. But concerning your question in the comments:

> can you also show a counter-example, i.e. a collection where two empty instances of different generic types would not be treated as equal?

You can of course implement your own `Collection` which **does** take into account the type information in the `equals` method. Here's a very simple example creating a `TypedList` wrapper around an arbitrary `List`:

```
static final class TypedList<T> extends AbstractList<T> {
    private final List<T> delegate;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public TypedList(List<T> delegate, Class<T> type) {
        this.delegate = Objects.requireNonNull(delegate);
        this.type = Objects.requireNonNull(type);
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return delegate.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return delegate.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!super.equals(obj)) {
            return false;
        }
        // Lists are equal, now additionally, check the type
        TypedList<?> other = (TypedList<?>) obj;
        return this.type.equals(other.type);
    }

    // hashCode omitted for brevity
}
```

Note, that you'll need to store the type explicitly due to the mentioned type erasure. Usage:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // true

list1 = new TypedList<>(list1, String.class);
list2 = new TypedList<>(list2, Integer.class);
System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // false
```

Comment: +1, that's a way I did not think of. Now, the next question would be this is possible to achieve this, without explicitly **passing** the type as a parameter (I'm fine if you extract it somehow from `delegate`. But I tried and failed.) I'll edit the question with this new detail.

Comment: Short and negative answer: It's not possible **without** the explicit type token. The `List<T>` will effectively just be a `List` at runtime, so that information is just not there. For the type in `Class<T>` it's different, as this is a “first-class citizen” -- even if it's just `Class` at runtime, it'll still hold the supplied type info (e.g. `String.class`, …)

Comment: Side note: `java.util.Collections` follows exactly the same principle, e.g. in this method: `java.util.Collections.checkedList(List<E>, Class<E>)` -- the type parameter needs to be passed as argument explicitly.

Comment: But watch out, `checkedList` will **not** handle your specific case of empty lists. It was rather just an example for the API design!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how individual sublcass that implement the collection interface handles the equals() method. For ArrayList, the implementation is in AbstractList which as follow:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator<?> e2 = ((List<?>) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

So it just return true if the opposite object is also a List and the size is same and every element is equals. So if both List are empty the result must be true.

Comment: "It really depends on how individual sublcass that implement the collection interface handles the equals() method." Well, what I'm asking is, whether it is really possible at all to handle `equals` differently then how `ArrayList` does. In other words: can you also show a counter-example, i.e. a collection where two empty instances of different generic types would not be treated as equal?

Answer (score 0):

> Generics are used for Type Checking at compile time.

If you create `ArrayList` like this:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // result:true
```

`list1` and `list2` will be equal because they are empty.`ArrayList` internally uses `Object[]` to store `ArrayList` entry.

If you add some entry to your array list:

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
list1.add("A");

List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
list2.add(1);

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2)); // result: false
```

This will return `false` because `ArrayList` entry are different

Comment: Ajit: I basically understand how it works, and why, in my case, it returns true. But I disagree with this statement "list1 and list2 will be equal because they are empty". To me, the two lists cannot be equal **conceptually**, because they are of different types. I'd rather see the fact that this can't be checked as a short-coming (or at least peculiarity) of Java, and was curious if there was a way around this.